# How to remove a worksheet from a workbook in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, spreadsheet, worksheet

Is there any possible way to remove a worksheet from a workbook? 
In my case I have to create the worksheets then fill them and after that I want to remove the empty sheets.

Is there any possible way to do that in ruby on rails? Method or other gem?

Comment: Yes, You can do it by using Roo Gem. You can check empty sheet and then delete the sheet if you get any empty sheet.

Comment: Really? I visited their website on github but the don't offer something like that. Can you tell me how would you do that? Or quote that from Roo?

Comment: First install Roo gem then, 
wb = Roo::Excelx.new 'chapter_data.xlsx'

wb.sheets.each do |sheet|
  wb.default_sheet = sheet
    if wb.first_row
      code.....
    end
end

The wb.first_row returns the index of the first non empty row.

Comment: But I can check the first non empty row and I know the sheet which I want to delete. What I need, is just the removing command, e.g. somthing like wb.remove(sheet). But that does not exist!

Comment: You are deleting the whole file!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using RubyXL gem.
Let's say your file name is file.xlsx and it is having 6 worksheets.

```
file = RubyXL::Parser.parse('file_path/file.xlsx')
puts file.count 
#It will show number of worksheets i.e, 6 
file.worksheets.delete(file['worksheet_name'])
# you can also give index of worksheet instead of its name
puts file.count
# It will show 5
file.write('file_path/file.xlsx')
# now you have a workbook with one sheet less
```